# Call array_map multiple times in PHP ( Vlookup in CSV using php array)

Tags: php, arrays, xml, rss

I have a problem with RSS parsing in PHP. I need to change some tags in RSS and also assign values to some of the data according to schema provided by another website. I manage to change Country names to ISO with array_map but when I'm trying to reuse the function for another value it's not working. I'm using different .csv files for each array.

Any Ideas ?

Example:

- Country name == ISO3 Code
- Job Type == Code (Consultancy = 234,Internship = 456 etc).

[CODE]:

```
$field_country = substr($field_country, strrpos($field_country, "|")+1);
$field_city = $feed[$x]['field_city'];
$field_job_type = $feed[$x]['field_job_type'];
$category = $feed[$x]['category'];
$category =  split('[|,]', $category); 
$field_job_experience = $feed[$x]['category'];
$field_job_experience = substr($field_job_experience, strrpos($field_job_experience, "Job Level|")+10);
$job_number = $feed[$x]['job_number'];
$pubDate = date('c', strtotime($feed[$x]['pubDate']));
$closeDate = date('c', strtotime($feed[$x]['closeDate']));
echo '<title>'.$title.'</title>';
echo '<pubDate>'.$pubDate.'</pubDate>';
echo '<field_job_closing_date>'.$closeDate.'</field_job_closing_date>';
$csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file('countries.csv'));
$findName= $field_country;
foreach($csv as $values)
{
  if($values[1]==$findName)  
    echo '<field_country>' .$values[2]. '</field_country>';       
};

echo '<field_city>'.$field_city.'</field_city>';
$csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file('job_category.csv'));
$findName= $field_job_type;
foreach($csv as $values)
{
  if($values[0]==$findName)  
    echo '<field_job_type>' .$values[1]. '</field_job_type>';       
};
echo '<field_career_categories>'.$category[1].'</field_career_categories>';
echo '<field_job_experience>'.$field_job_experience.'</field_job_experience>';
echo '<field_source>1979</field_source>';
echo '<field_theme></field_theme>';
                echo '</item>';

}

echo '</channel></rss></xml>';
```

Comment: This only happens when you try to use `array_map()` twice? What happens if you try getting the job types without doing the country first?

Comment: I can't see any way that the first array map could affect the second one. I suspect the problem is just that the job types don't match what you're looking for. Maybe the problem is that you're doing a case-sensitive comparison.

Comment: OK Solved there was problem with csv file, additional space at the beginning causing the problem. Thank you guys !

Comment: Use `trim()` to remove spaces at the beginning and end.